# is there any efficent alogrithm to check if i have atleast one valid combination to win from a group of valid combination?

Tags: algorithm

In my project, I have a requirement where they give a group of numbers and I need to check if they form some combination that is accepted.

Note: A combination is considered accepted if it exists in the group of valid combinations.

For example: suppose i have 3 numbers 1,2,3 so combination formed with them will be i.e {1} ,{2},{3},{1,2},{2,3},{1,3} and {1,2,3}   note: {1,2} and {2,1} is same in my case and same applied to the rest.

and accepted valid combinations are {1,3} and {2,1}  so i have 2 valid combinations in my set of combination ,hence i win.

is there any algorithm to find that out efficiently?

Note:
In input, they give with some valid combinations that are accepted as in the above example they provide me {1,3} and {2,1} if my numbers form any combination out of these combinations then I can win. and same applied to the rest statement referred to the ordering of elements i.e if I` have (3,1) then it is also accepted as the ordering of elements does not matter and 1,3 is accepted hence 3,1 is also accepted.

Any answer will be highly appreciated.

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking here. What do you mean by "form some combination", or "applied to the rest"? Make sure that you describe your problem clearly and unambiguously.

Comment: In input, they give with some valid combination that is accepted as in the above example they provide me {1,3} and {2,1} if my number form any combination out of these combinations then I can win. and same applied to the rest referred to the ordering of elements i.e if i have (3,1) that it is also accepted.

Comment: I guess that's a little clear. Are you saying, you'd like to check whether, given a set of "accepted sets", and given a "test set", you want to check whether some subset of your test set is a member of the set of accepted sets?

Comment: Yes, you are right but the order of elements inside the subsets of my set does not matter for example if {1,3} is inside the accepted set and {3,1} is inside subset of my test set then it is a valid match as ordering does not matter for my problem.

Comment: That's always the case. The difference between a "set" and a "sequence" is that "sets" are unordered.

Comment: i have a naive solution where I create permutations of the numbers in my test set and check if they form some accepted combination but i  don't think it is much efficient.

Comment: No idea why this question was closed as unclear. It's not *perfectly* clear, but especially with the edit it takes little effort to understand what's being asked.

Answer (score 2):

If the accepted set is relatively small (not N!) then one solution would be to create a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) and look for matches in it.

To look for matches you would only descend a link if the label associated with it is within your set. If you reach an end state you can stop searching.

To get the most benefits out of it you should sort the items in each accepted combination (that way you group all combinations that have '1' in them somewhere). I would guess that the best way to sort the values would be by how often they occur in the accepted set, but I don't have hard proof of that.

To build the trie the complexity if O(M * d) for M combinations of average lengh d. To check the complexity is also O(M * d) but should perform a lot better or more random cases (since you can eliminate more than one combination as soon as you don't find the next node).

Since M is there if you have a large number of accepted combinations then this might be slower.

Comment: Thanx man, I got your point  I had used trie before and I think I can create something from it.Let me test this approach.